# Pass output fields through a bolt of Apache Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

In the function `declareOutputFields` of my Bolt (which extends BaseBasicBolt), is there a simple way to declare the same fields that I received from the previous Bolt or Spout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible.

Spouts and Bolt are basically completely decoupled and only connected when assembling a topology. Thus, each Spout/Bolt must independently from its input, define the output schema.

Comment: Off-topic : you say bold are independent, but don't you code your whole bolt depending on the input you plan to give in the topology ?

Comment: Yes. Bolt have requirements about the input fields it reads. But all fields it does not processes, you can do whatever you want -- you can also add new field. This is especially true, if you do use field names instead on index to read them.

Comment: Ok tanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting way to deal with this problem. Note that this solution is not really matching my question because what I wanted to do is not really convenient to Storm guide rules, as Matthias Sax explained.

What I finally do is I ask fields in the constructor of my bolt. This way the fields I want to pass trough my bolt are given in my topology. This allow the user of the bolt to have more control on what come in and out of the bolt.

I think this is way more relevant than trying to pass everything like a mirror.